# How do I assign a DHCP address to a DHCP client using dhcpd?

Tags: centos, dhcp

I have installed in my CentOS guest #1 a server for DHCP, and the config file is like this:

[image]

And I am using my CentOS guest #2 to test that is working so I do to enp0s8, `ifdown enp0s8`, then I do `dhclient -d -I micliente enps0s3`, in order to assign an IP to that interface through my DHCP server and it does what in the picture is shown continuously:

[image]

I have to say that I am working with VirtualBox. So the question is..
How could I assign an IP through my service in CentOS #1 ?

If you need some more info let me know.